# Any subset of elements in an ultrafilter is in the ultrafilter

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

I am trying to prove the following fact:

> Given $\mathcal{F}$ an ultrafilter on $X$, suppose $ A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $B \subseteq A$, then  either $B$ or $A\backslash B$ are in $\mathcal{F}$

Recall:

> $\mathcal{F}$ is an ultrafilter if for all $F$ a filter on $X$,
>   $\mathcal{F} \not\subset F$

**My approach:**

Let $A \in \mathcal{F}$, and $B \subseteq A$, then suppose that $B \not \in \mathcal{F}$, we will show that $A \backslash B$ is in $\mathcal{F}$.

How to proceed from here?

Comment: Do you already know that for every $B$, either $B$ or $X\setminus B$ is in the ultrafilter?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, so just set $X = A$? If that's the case then the result helps

Comment: No, you can't set $X=A$, because $X$ and $A$ are both things you're _given_ here -- you can't choose what they are, beyond the stated assumptions.

Comment: @TheSilenceoftheCows $X$ is a fixed set on which the ultrafilter is based.  You cannot "set" it equal to something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already know that either $B$ or $X\setminus B$ is in $\mathcal F$.

Therefore if $B\notin\mathcal F$ it must be that $X\setminus B\in\mathcal F$, and since a filter is closed under finite intersections, we also have
$$ A \cap (X\setminus B) \in \mathcal F $$